# Django Email Templates Rendering as Text

Tags: django, django-templates, sendgrid, email

I am using trying to use the Django Dynamic Email Templates over SendGrid API. I understand there are some threads on this already, however, I have not been able to get these to work.

I have a basic template with some dynamic variables based on searches that I want to be emailed to the user. This is all works except the HTML is always rendered in the text despite applying what I have seen in a number of other threads here.

Would be grateful for any help here.

**Views.py**

```
def customer_selections_sent(request):
   #make=request.POST['makeselection']
    if request.method == 'GET':

        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        emailto = request.user.email_user
        user = request.user.username

        #call session values from SearchInventory function
        modelvalue =request.session.get('modelvalue')
        makevalue =request.session.get('makevalue')
        subject = 'ShowVroom Selections'

        #create variables to be used in the email template
        Email_Vars = {
            'user': user,
            'make': makevalue,
            'model': modelvalue,
            'domain': current_site.domain,
        }

        #create the email msg
        message = get_template('customer_selections_email.html').render(Email_Vars)
    html_message = get_template('customer_selections_email.html').render(Email_Vars)
    message.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
    

#send email


request.user.email_user(subject,message)
#request.user.email_user(subject, html_message)
#return redirect('customer_selections_sent')
return render(
    request,
    'customer_selections_sent.html',
    {
        'title':'Deals are on the way',
        'body':'We will email you shortly with more detail on your choices, you can respond to the dealers via the app until you agree to a viewing, test or purchase ',
        'year':datetime.now().year,
    }
)

send_mail(subject, message,  'Abc@xyz.org', emailto, fail_silently=False,html_message=html_message)
sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
response = sg.send(message)
#log respon
print(response.status_code)
print(response.body)
print(response.headers)
```

**HTML Template**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% load static %}
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Your ShowVroom Selections</title>

<img align="left" src="Logo1.png" alt="ShowVroom">
</head>

<body>
Hi {{ user }},

Here are your search selections;

<Strong>
    <br>Make;           {{make}} </br>
    <br>Model;          {{model}} </br>
</Strong>

</body>

<foot>
<a href = "mailto:info@showvroom.ie?subject = Offer&body = Message">
Contact ShowVroom
</a>
</foot>

</html>
```

**UPDATED VIEWS.PY**

```
def customer_selections_sent(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':

        #User variables
        emailto = request.user.email_user
        user = request.user.username

        #call session values from another function
        
        modelvalue =request.session.get('modelvalue')
        makevalue =request.session.get('makevalue')
        subject = 'ShowVroom Selections'

        #create variables to be used in the email template
        
        Email_Vars = {
            'user': user,
            'make': makevalue,
            'model': modelvalue,
            #'offer': DisplayInventory.GaragePrice,
            'domain': current_site.domain,
        }

        #create the email msg
        
        message = get_template('customer_selections_email.html').render(Email_Vars)
        html_message = get_template('customer_selections_email.html').render(Email_Vars)
        message.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html


    #Redirect to sent email Webpage
    
    request.user.email_user(subject,message)
    return render(
        request,
        'customer_selections_sent.html',
        {
            'title':'Deals are on the way',
            'body':'We will email you shortly with more detail on your choices, you can respond to the dealers via the app until you agree to a viewing, test or purchase ',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        }
    )
    
    #send email
    
    send_mail(subject, message,  'email@domain.com', emailto, fail_silently=False,html_message=html_message)
    sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
    response = sg.send(message)
    
    #log responses
    
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.body)
    print(response.headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply a value for the [`html_message` parameter to the send_email function.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#send-mail) As you've found, `message` is the value for the text version of the email.

Comment: So I have added an additional variable for the html_message and added the html_message to the send_mail function. I still appear to be doing something incorrectly here though as the email received is still text formatted html.

Comment: Please create a new code segment with the code you're running. Please also make sure it's formatted correctly. Currently it's very difficult to debug your situation.

Comment: That should be easier to follow now!

Comment: What is sending the email?

Comment: send_mail(subject, message,  'email@domain.com', emailto, fail_silently=False,html_message=html_message)

Comment: @johnperc Have you tried using `render_to_string`?